# JavaScript - Allow only numbers from paste without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I have this script that only allow numbers to be typed in and everything works great but I want to be able to paste only numbers if the user decides to use paste in an input.

The paste i'm referring to is `mouse paste` and `keyboard paste`. Paste in general. I tried to figure this out but I can not seem to find a way to do this.

Here is my code.

```js
//Prevent non numbers from keypress 
document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('keypress',preventNonNumbersInInput);

function preventNonNumbersInInput(event){

  var characters = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

  if(!(/[0-9]/.test(characters))){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}

//Prevent non numbers from being pasted only numbers can be pasted
document.querySelector('#numbers-only').addEventListener('paste',pasteTest);
function pasteTest(){
  //???
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='numbers-only'>
```

Comment: Francescos answer solves your problem - anything pasted into a number only input will have the rest removed or nothing will paste or a lower case `e` will paste for `error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

You can create a list of `invalid chars` to prevent on `keydown` i.e. paste.

Below is working code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("numbers-only");

var invalidChars = [
  "-",
  "+",
  "e",
  "."
];

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[e\+\-]/gi, "");
});

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (invalidChars.includes(e.key) || e.which === 38 || e.which === 40) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numbers-only" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice VicJordan but how can I avoid using the number input it's because I find those arrows annoying? The arrows that you use to change digits and how can I avoid using the arrows on the keyboard from change the digits.

Comment: @fsofb updated answer. Check it now! You can hide it using `CSS`

Comment: How can I also prevent the keyboard arrows from changing the digits in the input in other words I notice when I press the keyboard arrows it changes the digits.

Comment: @fsofb Updated answer for `disable keyboard arrows as well`. Check it out!

Comment: @fsofb you have mentioned many good requirements in comments here. I would suggest you to list down these requirements in your question as well so that other people can also get help from this.

Comment: Thanks vicJordan for your effort in trying to teach me by example It is how I want it actually this is for my client my client wanted this to be done with a text input rather than a number input if he don't approve of it i'm afraid I might have to ask this again under perhaps the same title with out using the number input  but I will grant you as the best answer thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an input you can easly change che input type to number.
The web browser will then take care of allowing only numbers.

```
<input type="number" id='phone-number'>
```

Comment: It still allows non-numbers in so your suggestion did not work for me. Is it possible to do this with the paste event?

Comment: It's strange when I do paste something it paste e or e's

Comment: @fsofb check out my answer.

Comment: This is because e is used to define numbers in scientific notion or 10^2 <=> 10e2

Comment: Thanks for the advice but how can I avoid using the number input it's because I find those arrows annoying? The arrows that you use to change digits and how can I avoid using the arrows on the keyboard from change the digits.